# I am trying to extract the modulus from the openssl command output using a bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, automation, openssl

Here is the sequence of commands that I am using to get the public key. Once I get the public key, I want to extract the modulus from the output.

1. openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:1024 -out key_rsa_private_1024.pem
2. openssl rsa -inform PEM -in key_rsa_private_1024.pem -text
3. openssl rsa -in key_rsa_private_1024.pem -pubout -out key_rsa_pub_1024.pub
4. openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in key_rsa_pub_1024.pub -text

The output looks like this -

```
Public-Key: (1024 bit)
Modulus:
    00:c5:f3:4b:c7:a3:c0:23:7a:0e:d4:f3:3e:07:06:
    4a:1e:7c:9d:ed:4d:23:8f:4b:00:6f:bc:f3:05:3b:
    62:2e:35:00:78:d2:af:7f:7a:f0:fe:e3:c0:37:f6:
    c3:58:4f:34:91:b7:91:a1:32:3e:d5:28:ab:f7:5d:
    5e:e6:ba:14:76:b8:84:d6:45:2d:48:47:68:53:39:
    54:55:d3:70:ef:f8:92:09:78:77:31:d6:ee:e5:6f:
    8e:59:4d:c2:40:1f:6d:7b:32:c7:b6:91:c4:75:9e:
    95:d6:d7:d9:39:60:f7:13:d5:95:4e:ff:4b:7d:dc:
    e8:fd:b0:a1:25:57:32:f5:ff
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDF80vHo8Ajeg7U8z4HBkoefJ3t
TSOPSwBvvPMFO2IuNQB40q9/evD+48A39sNYTzSRt5GhMj7VKKv3XV7muhR2uITW
RS1IR2hTOVRV03Dv+JIJeHcx1u7lb45ZTcJAH217Mse2kcR1npXW19k5YPcT1ZVO
/0t93Oj9sKElVzL1/wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I explored some commands such as grep and awk, but these do not give me the output I need.

Comment: I suggest to append  `| grep '^ '`.

Comment: Do you want all the modulus parts assembled into one single line?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the desired output.

Comment: Hi @Grobu, I am just trying to extract the modulus output, it is fine in any format.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is probably to use the `-modulus` option of `openssl rsa`:

```
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in key_rsa_pub_1024.pub -noout -modulus
```

This will output:

```
Modulus=DC861A72302F93EB42E56118C6D470261B457B0AA6B500A62EF6E0EE797A68042185B773489C037DD710AAAC424F3BBF90093B29CDF05850D333B27BE4751B41C87DC48632980CF030073FB33450BD72C41B5AE1F2DFD375AB193A31711437CBF08608D0DDAD0570E47EFC55F990F916839320F9FA7BC3EBE9C12DBEDDD479EF
```

If you want to drop the `Modulus=` part, then:

```
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in key_rsa_pub_1024.pub -noout -modulus | cut -f2 -d=
```

Comment: I tried this and I get other data too, I think adding grep '^ ' to my command gave me the desired result.